# Dynamically allocating strings within a struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

If I have a struct defined as such:

```
typedef struct{

    char a[];

}my_struct_t;
```

How do you allocate memory for a string with `malloc()` such that it is stored in `my_struct_t`?

Comment: That looks suspiciously like `char *` with a funny type.

Answer (score 4):

Code could use a *flexible array member* [FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) to the store *string* in the structure.    Available since C99.  It requires at least one more member in the `struct` than OP's code.

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*. ... C11 §6.7.2. 18

```
typedef struct fam {
  size_t sz;  // At least 1 member. 
  char a[];   // flexible array member - must be last.
} my_struct_t;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

my_struct_t *foo(const char *src) {
  size_t sz = strlen(src) + 1;

  // Allocate enough space for *st and the string.
  // `sizeof *st` does not count the flexible array member. 
  struct fam *st = malloc(sizeof *st + sz);
  assert(st);

  st->sz = sz;
  memcpy(st->a, src, sz);
  return st;
}
```

---

As exactly coded, the below is not valid C syntax.  Of course various compilers offer language extensions.

```
typedef struct{
    char a[];
}my_struct_t;
```

Comment: Something about this seems dangerous. I have never seen it before. Very interesting.

Comment: @Secto Kia Older C would use the last member as `char a[1];` so the technique has been used for decades.  That older technique had issues that are satisfied with C99 and `char a[];` ( alignment, `sizeof struct`, analysis tools).  Like many tools in the C shed: use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @SectoKia Note: often `malloc(sizeof *st + sizeof *(st->a) * N);` idiom is used when the last array element is not `char []`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
     char* a;
} my_struct_t;


int main() 
{
    my_struct_t* s = malloc(sizeof(my_struct_t));
    s->a = malloc(100);
    // Rest of Code
    free(s->a);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Array of 100 chars.

Comment: OP requested "...allocate memory for a string with malloc such that it is stored in `my_struct_t`?"  .  This answer likely meets OP's goal, yet it does not store the string _in_ the structure, but stores a pointer to the _future_ string.